# How to place a marker on MAP tag using html & jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, maps

I am trying to create a mapped image. I am done with setting the coordinates etc.

Find image:
[image: map]

Now I need to place a marker on several areas on this.

Example required image:
[image: map with marker]

How can I achieve this.

Map code:

```
<img src="/images/mapimage.jpg" alt="States Map" usemap="#Map">
<map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area coords="46,378,216,408,219,534,46,529" shape="poly" href="#" title="Alaska" alt="">
    <area coords="247,456,368,487,354,535,246,529" shape="poly" href="#" title="Hawai" alt="">
    <area coords="91,2,174,25,163,79,72,56" shape="poly" href="#" title="Washington" alt="">
    <area coords="178,27,341,51,333,127,209,110" shape="poly" href="#" title="Montana" alt="">
    <area coords="176,25,209,115,239,116,227,171,151,155,148,152" shape="poly" href="#" title="Idaho" alt="">
    <area coords="241,116,335,126,330,206,227,193" shape="poly" href="#" title="Wyoming" alt="">
    <area alt="" title="Oregon" href="#" shape="poly" coords="72,58,162,81,144,156,47,129">
    <area coords="44,130,100,148,89,205,150,295,141,346,103,341,89,304,60,290,38,188" shape="poly" href="#" title="California" alt="">
    <area coords="104,147,187,167,170,262,151,293,91,201" shape="poly" href="#" title="Nevada" alt="">
    <area coords="190,166,228,175,225,193,255,200,244,275,172,262" shape="poly" href="#" title="Utah" alt="">
    <area coords="171,266,242,278,229,389,198,382,147,348,152,302" shape="poly" href="#" title="Arizona" alt="">
    <area coords="248,277,352,289,345,384,276,383,231,386" shape="poly" href="#" title="Colorado" alt="">
    <area coords="258,199,359,209,353,280,247,273" shape="poly" href="#" title="New Mexico" alt="">
    <area alt="" title="Nebraska" href="#" shape="poly" coords="335,168,443,175,457,232,362,229,358,207,334,207">
    <area alt="" title="South Dakota" href="#" shape="poly" coords="339,109,442,113,441,175,333,165">
    <area alt="" title="North Dakota" href="#" shape="poly" coords="345,50,432,56,441,110,339,106">
    <area alt="" title="Texas" href="#" shape="poly" coords="354,302,347,389,280,383,325,446,346,430,393,495,428,505,427,469,485,435,479,359,384,340,386,304">
    <area alt="" title="Oklahoma" href="#" shape="poly" coords="357,285,470,292,474,356,430,356,387,337,388,303,353,300">
    <area alt="" title="Kansas" href="#" shape="poly" coords="360,230,458,234,471,250,471,289,353,282">
    <area alt="" title="Minnesota" href="#" shape="poly" coords="436,55,472,59,531,71,501,93,494,131,516,159,442,158">
    <area alt="" title="Missouri" href="#" shape="poly" coords="455,222,519,221,557,285,553,298,475,299,474,250">
    <area alt="" title="Arkansas" href="#" shape="poly" coords="473,300,551,298,530,366,484,368,482,358,476,358">
    <area alt="" title="Louisiana" href="#" shape="poly" coords="487,434,520,435,540,443,564,442,552,406,525,406,532,387,528,369,482,370"> 
</map>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it adding an absolute element with transparent png over the map.  To make it easier I added a wrapper `div` with ID `container`.  To add the markers I'm using a little javascript and some CSS.

```js
var points = [{x:258, y:199}, 
     {x:359, y:209}, 
     {x:345, y:384}, 
     {x:276, y:383},
     {x:231, y:386}];
function drawPoint(point){   
        div = $("<div />")
            div.attr("class", 'cityMarker')
            div.css("top", point.y-8)
            div.css("left", point.x+85)
            $("#container").append(div)
}
for (var i = 0, len = points.length; i < len; i++) {
  drawPoint(points[i]);
}
```

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
}
.cityMarker {
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background: url("http://www.myiconfinder.com/uploads/iconsets/256-256-f900504cdc9f243b1c6852985c35a7f7.png");
    position: absolute;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    top: 2px;
    left: 91px;
    opacity: 1.0;
    -moz-opacity: 1.0;
    -webkit-opacity: 1.0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
<img id="imgMap" src="http://image.prntscr.com/image/918feebe981d45adbee07710e04c4ef5.png" alt="States Map" usemap="#Map">
   <map name="Map" id="Map">
<area coords="46,378,216,408,219,534,46,529" shape="poly" href="#" title="Alaska" alt="">
<area coords="247,456,368,487,354,535,246,529" shape="poly" href="#" title="Hawai" alt="">
<area coords="91,2,174,25,163,79,72,56" shape="poly" href="#" title="Washington" alt="">
<area coords="178,27,341,51,333,127,209,110" shape="poly" href="#" title="Montana" alt="">
<area coords="176,25,209,115,239,116,227,171,151,155,148,152" shape="poly" href="#" title="Idaho" alt="">
<area coords="241,116,335,126,330,206,227,193" shape="poly" href="#" title="Wyoming" alt="">
<area alt="" title="Oregon" href="#" shape="poly" coords="72,58,162,81,144,156,47,129">
<area coords="44,130,100,148,89,205,150,295,141,346,103,341,89,304,60,290,38,188" shape="poly" href="#" title="California" alt="">
<area coords="104,147,187,167,170,262,151,293,91,201" shape="poly" href="#" title="Nevada" alt="">
<area coords="190,166,228,175,225,193,255,200,244,275,172,262" shape="poly" href="#" title="Utah" alt="">
<area coords="171,266,242,278,229,389,198,382,147,348,152,302" shape="poly" href="#" title="Arizona" alt="">
<area coords="248,277,352,289,345,384,276,383,231,386" shape="poly" href="#" title="New Mexico" alt="">
<area coords="258,199,359,209,353,280,247,273" shape="poly" href="#" title="Colorado" alt="">
<area alt="" title="Nebraska" href="#" shape="poly" coords="335,168,443,175,457,232,362,229,358,207,334,207">
<area alt="" title="South Dakota" href="#" shape="poly" coords="339,109,442,113,441,175,333,165">
<area alt="" title="North Dakota" href="#" shape="poly" coords="345,50,432,56,441,110,339,106">
<area alt="" title="Texas" href="#" shape="poly" coords="354,302,347,389,280,383,325,446,346,430,393,495,428,505,427,469,485,435,479,359,384,340,386,304">
<area alt="" title="Oklahoma" href="#" shape="poly" coords="357,285,470,292,474,356,430,356,387,337,388,303,353,300">
<area alt="" title="Kansas" href="#" shape="poly" coords="360,230,458,234,471,250,471,289,353,282">
<area alt="" title="Minnesota" href="#" shape="poly" coords="436,55,472,59,531,71,501,93,494,131,516,159,442,158">
<area alt="" title="Missouri" href="#" shape="poly" coords="455,222,519,221,557,285,553,298,475,299,474,250">
<area alt="" title="Arkansas" href="#" shape="poly" coords="473,300,551,298,530,366,484,368,482,358,476,358">
<area alt="" title="Louisiana" href="#" shape="poly" coords="487,434,520,435,540,443,564,442,552,406,525,406,532,387,528,369,482,370"> 
</map>
</div>
```

Now you just need to add your points to the array and adjust coordinates.  As you can see I added 85px to x and -8px on y.  I had to do it in order to fix the offset on the image and my own 25x25 div. Also, there is an offset between the image and the map coord.

Finally, I'm not from USA but I think you swapped Colorado and New Mexico on your map.  I fixed on this snippet.

Comment: This answer works actually pretty nice... Just not in the preview of SO. Here is the same example: https://jsfiddle.net/wittich/ph73ejrv/